# I want to convert the arrays into an image an then animate it

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, conways-game-of-life

So I was trying to come up with a Conway's Game of Life code, and this lead me to this one. It may not be the most efficient one, but I'm a begginer coder and I wanted to keep things simple. All I want to do is to animate the game, and not only display the last generation of the game. Also, I'd like to know how to run the game indefinately, because as you can see this code has a pre determined number of generations. Thanks in advance for your help and here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.random.randint(2, size=(50,50))

for b in range (0,100):
    y=np.zeros((50,50), dtype=np.int)
    for c in range(1,48):
        for d in range(1,48):
            if x[c][d]==1:
                if x[c][d-1]+x[c][d+1]+x[c-1][d-1]+x[c-1][d]+x[c-1][d+1]+x[c+1][d-1]+x[c+1][d]+x[c+1][d+1]<2 or x[c][d-1]+x[c][d+1]+x[c-1][d-1]+x[c-1][d]+x[c-1][d+1]+x[c+1][d-1]+x[c+1][d]+x[c+1][d+1]>3:
                    y[c][d]=0
                else:
                    y[c][d]=1
            if x[c][d]==0:
                if x[c][d-1]+x[c][d+1]+x[c-1][d-1]+x[c-1][d]+x[c-1][d+1]+x[c+1][d-1]+x[c+1][d]+x[c+1][d+1]==3:
                    y[c][d]=1
                else:
                    y[c][d]=0
    x=y.copy()

plt.imshow(x)
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Unrelated, but since you already use numpy you could use slicing to get all the neighbors, like `np.sum(x[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2]) - x[i,j]`. Also I wouldn't compute the same number of neighbors two or three times, just assign a variable to it.   Finally, an animation example for `imshow` is given here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/dynamic_image.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had dreadful luck with the various animation examples out there (and related blocking/nonblocking examples), when running on a Macbook.

A simple thing that works for me:

`...
x=np.random.randint(2, size=(50,50))
p = plt.imshow(x)
...
    x = y.copy()
    p.set_data(x)
    plt.pause(.1)`

Comment: Do you think it is possible to animate it without matplotlib? It seems to me that this resource is a bit slow and it takes a while to compute and plot the image.

Comment: If not matplotlib, you could look into openCV (it is famously difficult to get installed, good luck). Meanwhile, here's a delightful post on speeding up matplotlib (not all of these work for me on a Mac, but some do): http://bastibe.de/2013-05-30-speeding-up-matplotlib.html. If you liked my answer, be sure to accept it to close the question.